# Qt mouse cursor does not change when opening dialog after drop event

Tags: c++, drag-and-drop, qt4

I am using Qt for C++ and have a dropEvent which opens a dialog. However when the dialog opens, the mouse cursor retains the drop cursor instead of going back to the generic default cursor. This is strange behavior especially while clicking on buttons on the dialog. Below is a rough outline of my dropEvent code.

```
MyClass::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
   //do some stuff
   event->accept();

   MyDialog::runDialog(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}

MyDialog::runDialog(arg1, arg2, arg3)
{
   MyDialog dlg(arg1, arg2, arg3);

   if(dlg.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
   {
      //do some stuff
   }
}
```

NOTE: Unfortunately I cannot post pictures of the cursors yet because I do not have enough rep.

Comment: I believe you should call event->acceptAction(); instead of event->accept();

Comment: No, Qt allows either event->accept() or event->acceptProposedAction(); In this case event->accept() is the correct option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a workaround that I am using since it isn't feasible to change the dialog code from exec to show.

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
   //qRegisterMetaType was necessary for two of my parameters.
   qRegisterMetaType<arg1>("arg1");
   qRegisterMetaType<arg2>("arg2");
   connect(this, SIGNAL(signalDialog(arg1, arg2, arg3)), this, SLOT(runDialog(arg1, arg2, arg3)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
}

MyClass::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
   //do some stuff
   event->accept();

   emit signalDialog(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}

MyClass::runDialog(arg1, arg2, arg3)
{
  MyDialog::runDialog(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}

MyDialog::runDialog(arg1, arg2, arg3)
{
   MyDialog dlg(arg1, arg2, arg3);

   if(dlg.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
   {
      //do some stuff
   }
}
```

The cursor was changed back to the default correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor()
```